# Path-connectedness of the set of complex matrices with simple eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

I try to prove that  the set of complex matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with simple eigenvalues is path-connected. I think that it suffices to show that the set of diagonal matrices witch  diagonal elements are pairewise distinct is path-connected but I cannot prove it.

Comment: I'm not sure if these two are equivalent. But the latter follows from the fact that $\mathbb{C}\backslash A$ is path connected for any finite set $A$. So you take two diagonal matrices $M,N$ and then you connect them by constructing consecutive path for each diagonal value, a path that avoids other values on the diagonal.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Expression_in_terms_of_the_roots

Comment: Let's $G_n$ the set of diagonal matrices witch diagonal elements are pairewise distinct and $H_n$ the set of  matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with simple eigenvalues. The map  $\phi:GL_n(\mathbb{C})\times G_n\to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ defined by $\phi(P,D)=P^{-1}DP$ is continuous and $\phi(GL_n(\mathbb{C})\times G_n)=H_n$. It is known that  $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is path-connected, so if we prove that $G_n$ is path-connected, then  $H_n$ is also path-connected.